# Sample Java code to append into an excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Can I a get a pointer to a sample java code which can append data into an already existing excel sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Quick Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) on using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)'s Excel Component API.

It sounds like you want to open a file, set some cell values, and write back to a file.

See the section "Files vs InputStreams" for how to open a file and "Creating Cells" for how to set values for cells and write to a file.